# GROUP BY on a column to get remove nulls

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table

```
Order_ID  Loc_ID   OrderDate    ShippingDate  DeliveryDate
10           2      10/12/2018   null          null
10           2      null         null          18/12/2018
10           2      null         12/13/2019     null
```

Basically, every time a date is recorded, it is added as a row. I want the table to look like this:

```
Order_ID   Loc_ID  Order_Date     ShippingDate   DeliveryDate
10            2    10/12/2018     13/12/2018     18/12/2018
```

Can someone tell me how I should do this?

Comment: Do you want the table to look like that, or a result set that looks like that? if the former, you probably want to look into UPDATE; if the latter, the answers already provided cover that.

Comment: Then you should use an UNPDATE, not an INSERT in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Use `MAX`:

```
SELECT Order_ID,
       Loc_ID,
       MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate,
       MAX(ShippingDate) AS ShippingDate,
       MAX(DeliveryDate) AS DeliveryDate
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY Order_ID,
         Loc_ID;
```

When ordering data `NULL` has the lowest value, so any non-`NULL` value will have a "greater" value. As a result `MAX` will return the non-`NULL` value.

Answer (score 2):

A simple aggregation should do the trick

**Example**

```
Select Order_ID  
      ,Loc_ID   
      ,OrderDate    = max(OrderDate)
      ,ShippingDate = max(ShippingDate)
      ,DeliveryDate = max(DeliveryDate)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Order_ID,Loc_ID
```