# MySQL - group rows with different columns discarding Null values

Tags: mysql, join, select, null, row

I am fairly new and need help with this!

How can I do a `SELECT` in MySQL to obtain from the following Table a result that joins all the rows in one with its columns?

Table:

| ID | Name | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | Null | Null | Null |
| 1 | ABC | Null | 456 | Null | Null |
| 1 | ABC | Null | Null | 789 | Null |
| 1 | ABC | Null | Null | Null | 900 |

Output:

| ID | Name | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 123 | 456 | 789 | 900 |

I was researching and I don't even know how to search for the function!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exact question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59272294/group-by-on-a-column-to-get-remove-nulls)

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       MAX(Type1) AS Type1,
       MAX(Type2) AS Type2,
       MAX(Type3) AS Type3
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID,
         NAME;
```